# UI Automation CreatePropertyCondition 0xc0000005

Tags: ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I tried to re-use code (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff625913(v=vs.85).aspx#FindByName), but I want to wrap it in a simple class. When I'm run this code it falls on:

```
hr = g_pAutomation->CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_ClassNamePropertyId, varProp, &pCondition);
```

with 0xc0000005.

I know, it because of empty or broken pointer. But when I run this code without any classes (from `main()`), it works perfect.

What should I read and from where to understand why it happens?

```
#pragma once

#include <UIAutomation.h>

class Automator
{
protected:
     IUIAutomation* g_pAutomation;
     IUIAutomationElement* pRoot;
     IUIAutomationElementArray* pArrFound;
     IUIAutomationElement* pFound;
public:
     Automator(void);
    ~Automator(void);
     void ClearResources(void);
     void FindAllWindows(void);
};


#include "Automator.h"

Automator::Automator(void)
{
     pRoot = NULL;
     pArrFound = NULL;
     pFound = NULL;
     g_pAutomation = NULL;

     CoInitialize(NULL);
     HRESULT hr;
     hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(CUIAutomation), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
          __uuidof(IUIAutomation), (void**)&g_pAutomation);
     if(FAILED(hr))
          ClearResources();
     else
     {
          hr = g_pAutomation->GetRootElement(&pRoot);
          if (FAILED(hr) || pRoot == NULL)
            ClearResources();
     }

}

Automator::~Automator(void)
{
    ClearResources();
}

//
//Doesn't work
//
void Automator::FindAllWindows(void)
{
    VARIANT varProp;
    varProp.vt = VT_BSTR;
    varProp.bstrVal = L"";

    IUIAutomationCondition* pCondition;
    HRESULT hr = NULL;
    if (g_pAutomation != NULL)
    {
         hr = g_pAutomation->CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_ClassNamePropertyId, varProp,     &pCondition);
         if(FAILED(hr))
         {
              if (pCondition != NULL)
                  pCondition->Release();
              ClearResources();
         }
         else
         {
              pRoot->FindAll(TreeScope_Subtree, pCondition, &pArrFound);
         }
    }

    if(pCondition != NULL)
         pCondition->Release();
}

void Automator::ClearResources(void)
{
     if (pRoot != NULL)
         pRoot->Release();

     if (pArrFound != NULL)
         pArrFound->Release();

     if (pFound != NULL)
         pFound->Release();

     if (g_pAutomation != NULL)
         g_pAutomation->Release();

     CoUninitialize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues:

1. Don't call CoInitialize/CoUninitialize from class constructors/destructors; do it inside your `main` (or thread entry point).  A fair amount of code runs before `main()` gets called (static class initializers, for one) and having that run outside `main()` can result in problems.
2. You haven't shown your `main()` - where are you creating your `Automator` object?  I suspect you haven't actually created an `Automator`, which is why it's crashing.

If I were going to write your `main`, it would look like this:

```
_wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv)
{
    CoInitialize();
    {
        Automator automator;
        automator.FindAllWindows();
    }
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

The extra scope bracket is there to insure that the Automator destructor runs before CoUninitialize().